# Retrieving the text between 2 XML tags from the DOM Parser

Tags: xml, visual-c++, dom, com

I'm trying to do this in my C++ program and I'm using COM Interop.

The XML I'm trying to parse looks like this --

```
<PluginNameList version =”1.0”>
   <PluginName> Plug-in1 </PluginName>              
   <PluginName> Plug-in2 </PluginName>
</PluginNameList>
```

I'm trying to retrieve the text between

```
 <PluginName> </PluginNmae> tags.
```

Would I be using IXMLDOMElement or IXMLDOMNode? And which method from these classes?

I think it's fairly trivial, but I'm not able to find a direct answer anywhere.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use method get_text in IXMLDOMNode. See [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762687%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#Y312) for more info

Comment: But a  node is very generic right? An element descends from node and I what I want further is the text in the element. A node could be containing the the tags and the text too. But do you mean I have to parse enough to come to the first tag of the element? And the next time the node can contain the text?

Comment: Yes IXMLDOMNode is base interface for other DOM objects. It contained collection of child nodes and text between tags. Other nested interfaces provide additional functionality (IXMLDOMElement for work with xml attributes and etc.) IXMLDOMNode enough for getting text value and child enumeration.

Comment: Just realized that get_text is also a part of IXMLDOMElement. This mgiht work too right?

Comment: Yes of course IXMLDOMElement is child of IXMLDOMNode and include all methods and properties